# JSON_OBJECT_T doesnot exist in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I was trying the following code:

```
DECLARE 
l_object   json_object_t; 
BEGIN 
  l_object := json_object_t.parse ('{"Name":"Elvis"}'); 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_object.get_string ('Name')); 
END;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'JSON_OBJECT_T' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 15:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or 
malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 26:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or 
malformed
ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I cannot use any of the following `JSON_OBJECT_T`; `JSON_ARRAY_T`; `JSON_OBJECT_T`; `JSON_KEY_LIST`; `JSON_ARRAY_T`; `JSON_OBJECT_T`; `JSON_KEY_LIST`;

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I was using Oracle 12cR1. Tested in 12cR2 and it is working fine. But in my project, i cant update it to 12cR2. Is there a way I can write a java method and use it inside `COLUMNS` section of `JSON_TABLE`?

Comment: i'm using Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 and your code works. maybe you shoul ask your dba if you have privileges to use that objects

Comment: The SQL construct JSON_OBJECT and its PL/SQL analogue  JSON_OBJECT_T are new to 12cR2. Perhaps you are still using 12cR1?

Comment: Thanks! I was using 12cR1. Updated the DB and it worked fine..

Comment: Is there a way that I can use a java method inside 'COLUMNS' section of JSON_TABLE? (Updation to R2 can't be done in my project) @APC

Comment: I worked on 12cR1 project last year where we need to pass a JSON payload to a web service. What we did was generate the payload using Oracle's XML functionality and the Java guys wrote something to turn XML into JSON in the middle tier. Maybe something like that may work for you too.